# Unable to set working directory for split vector layer tool

Tags: qgis, layers, vector, splitting, directory

I have some data in a .shp layer that I want to separate into multiple vector layers based on ID.

When I navigate to the Split Vector Layer tool, I can select my input layer, unique field ID, and adjust the advanced parameters and output layer. I select the appropriate input layer, set my output file type to .shp, but when I click "Run", the tool processes, but no file is created. From what I've read online, I must set a working directory under the ouput directory option. So I try to "save to directory", but for some reason, instead of allowing my to set the directory, it gives me the option to "Open" (see photo) but nothing else. When I choose my desired directory, then click "Open" it just exits out of the split vector layer tool and nothing happens.

How do I set a working directory and/or save the new split vector layers into QGIS and my computer?

[image: Problem]Computing details: QGIS 3.28.3-Firenze; MacOS Ventura 13.6.1

Answer (score 1):

As @enolan pointed out, copying the folder path and pasting it into the "output directory" text box did the trick and saved all of the .shp files to my computer, which I was then able to load into QGIS.